# Water diving and depth measuring equipment

Tags: measurements, land-survey, waterways

We go to villages and forest to deepwell rig for water. Can anyone help in identifying a GPS and water depth measurement devices please?

---

we do 4-6" deepwell rigging for ground water in mozambique with rigs mounted on trucks

Comment: Could you give a little bit more information on your set up?

Answer (score 1):

I once used contact gauges to measure ground water at one to two meter deep pipe wells in weekly intervals manually. Similar to those [here](http://www.ott.com/en-uk/products/water-level/ott-contact-gauges/). Its a bit time-consuming but works well for a limited number of stations. It looks like they exist in different quality stages, for deeper wells and maybe even with integrated gps-data logging, but not sure though. In any case you should be able to measure location by a separate gps receiver.